# Mr Cool DIY single split. How to connect line w/ black tip?

Tags: air-conditioning

Copper line in handler that should be connected to charged line w/black yip (see photo), how to w/o losing freon out of black tip which is pressurized.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do the instructions say?

Answer (score 2):

That extra-shiny black thing on the tip looks like a "dust cap" to keep dust out of the fitting and protect threads from damage.  I bet it pops off easily.

Code actually requires you to follow the instructions carefully - because the safety rating depends on the instructions being followed.

Answer (score 1):

That black plastic cap is a protective cap and needs to be removed to make the connection. Or the mr cool units I looked at a year or 2 back did. If the fittings are self sealing and the plastic caps are protective.

Hold the brass fitting and unscrew the plastic.

If these are not self sealing the system is a model that requires a vacuum pump to purge the line set.

The mfg instructions should tell you this and if they are flair fittings the linesets are shipped filled with nitrogen to keep them dry.